# The C language and Mac OSX

Tags: c, macos

I was wondering whether anybody here could help me better understand the relationship between OSX and C. There's some developer information related to C++ in xcode but nothing for C.

I believe one fundamental difference is that osx uses libc as opposed to glibc. Can anybody point me to libc documentation? I can't seem to find any.

I've seen the usr/includes folder but all that does is make me wonder where I can get a reference that elucidates all the options available to me. For instance, I just discovered `<tree.h>`. That's all well and good but is there any documentation? Or do I need to trawl the includes folder?

Comment: Most C libraries are similar in their core, with the occasional well known quirks.  I believe once you have xcode installed, you'll have a compiler at the command line and a useful collection of reference pages for `man` to read - ie, type `man printf` and see what happens.

Comment: It's rather unclear what you're asking.  C is one of the languages supported for development on OS X.  OS X provides a complete C standard library, and quite a few other C libraries besides.  The standard library is documented both by the C standard, and also in man pages.  "libc" is just a generic name for any C standard library.  "glibc" is one specific implementation of that library, whereas Apple uses their own implementation for OS X, which is part of the libSystem library.

Comment: OS X is a BSD Unix derivative at its heart. There are plenty of standard C references around, and you can use something like [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment](http://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Programming-UNIX-Environment-Edition/dp/0321637739) for the Unix stuff, as well as the man pages. For all the Cocoa pieces, Apple has plenty of documentation. Poking around in the `usr/include` folders is a pretty inefficient way of going about things, and there's a lot of stuff in there you shouldn't be directly using.

Comment: Thank you all! I appreciate your patience. @StephenCanon, where can I find information about those additional C libraries?
PaulGriffiths I just picked up a copy of advanced programming in the unix environment so I will turn to that.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you're asking whether the functionality that OSX provides to you as a programmer is partially different from other *nix systems; focusing on the functionality that OSX's implementation of the C Standard Library provides you with.

Now keep in mind that while the C Standard Library is a very common way to take advantage of the functionality the operating system kernel exposes, it's not the only way. You can use other low-level libraries, or write low-level functions yourself.

Having said that, consider the following:

- OSX, like many other *nix systems, is "mostly POSIX-compliant". Meaning that its particular C Standard Library implementation will likely expose [headers defined by the POSIX standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_POSIX_library). This is the stuff you can rely on regardless of whether you use `libc`, `glibc`, or some other implementation of the C Standard Library.
- Depending on the particular C Standard Library you're using, it might come with additional functionality, like [BSD libc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library#BSD_libc) - we say "superset of the POSIX Standard Library" to that. While it can contain implementations of things specific to BSD (and therefore OSX), it mostly seems to contain things that can be implemented regardless of the operating system flavour. For example, the `sys/tree.h` header that you mention is "an implementation of Red-black tree and Splay tree" - by no means something that couldn't have been implemented on a Linux system!

To sum up:

- OSX comes with an implementation of the C Standard Library called `BSD libc` that provides some additional headers on top of what the POSIX Standard defines.
- The difference in functionality between the [XNU kernel used by OSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNU) and other *nix kernels will not necessarily be captured in the difference between the C Standard Library implementations. If you want to know what the XNU kernel can do for you that the Linux kernel can't, the place to start is with the kernels themselves.

**So your question can be split into:**

- What is the difference between `glibc` and `BSD libc`?

and

- What is the difference between the XNU kernel and the Linux kernel?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking.

OS X is based on top of FreeBSD, a POSIX-compliant UNIX operating system. The relationship between OS X and C is that C is one of many programming languages that you can code in to develop for the platform (C is the core of Objective-C, an otherwise unused language that Apple champions).

*OS X* doesn't use libc. clang, the *compiler* that ships as part of Apple's developer tools package for OS X, uses libc. There's a difference. If you want to use glib, grab GCC from Homebrew or Macports and use it to compile your programs instead of clang.

Lastly, you can't find documentation for libc, as all C libraries, like libc, glibc, etc, all provide the same set of functions if they are standards-compliant. There tend to be few differences end-user-wise between the different C libraries; so, if you want to find out about a header file, use `man`, like this: `man clang` to read clang documentation, for example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @SevenBits. This was helpful. I guess what i meant was what are the implementation details of OSX and how do they differ from other C libraries. My working assumption is that those differences would be cataloged in man pages unique to the system.